# Two ways to put image into graphics context - which is better?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I've noticed examples of two ways to put images into core graphics.  One is much simpler than the other.  So what's the advantage of the second, more sophisticated, approach?  Is it faster?

example 1

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(70, 330, 40, 40);
[myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
[myImage release];
```

example 2

```
// Load image from application bundle
NSString* imageFileName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"picture.png"];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([imageFileName UTF8String]);
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, true,      kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

// Draw image
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 70, 370 );
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40), image);
CGImageRelease(image);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly comparing the two, the advantage of the second method is that it doesn't put the image into the `+[UIImage imageNamed:]` cache. It's not possible for you to remove images from that cache, so you may be better off not using `imageNamed:`.

However, you can get the best of both worlds.

First off, use `-[NSBundle URLForResource:withExtension:]` to get the URL to the image. This simplifies that step over getting the resource directory path or URL and appending the filename to it yourself.

Second, use `+[UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:]` to create the image, passing the URL you obtained from the NSBundle.

From there, continue on as in your first example. The total will be only five lines (two of them replacing the first line of your first example).

Answer (score 0):

In example 1 you are just gonna show the image in the view as it is, and it is good too to show static images.

But in example 2 you are using core graphics to display the image so you can do more operations on it, more than just a static image. You can rotate it, scale it, translate it, reduce its alpha value and many more that i also not aware of.

so it depends on your choice of use. whether you want to just show the image or want it to do something more than that.if you are begineer and want to develop utility apps than i dont think you will ever use 2 option. but if you want to develop games or want to animate the image you will use should 2 option.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any advantages for the second way. It has the disadvantage of having more steps. If you use the first way and have a UIImage and you need a CGImageRef you can access it through the CGImage property. I find myself using the first most often. When you have a UIImage you can use your own UIImageView to add it to a view hierarchy or you can assign it directly to some of the UIKit objects like UITableViewCell's imageView. If you get the CGImageRef (second way) then you would need to imageWithCGImage: first...